# command egrep to extract one line if find the same word

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I will show you the output of this command:

```
[root@test ~]# df -P -k -t xfs | egrep '*/PATH whichI don't have/*'
```

When I run my command I have the output bellow:

```
[root@test ~]# df -P -k -t xfs | egrep '*/PATH whichI don't have/*'
10.20.30.40:/var/contain/name1  3877121024 215982080 3661138944       6% /fofo
10.20.30.50:/var/beta/name2  3877121024 215982080 3661138944       6% /fofo
10.20.30.40:/var/contain/name2  3877121024 215982080 3661138944       6% /fofo
10.20.30.50:/var/beta/toto  3877121024 215982080 3661138944       6% /fofo
10.20.30.60:/var/alpha/name2  3877121024 215982080 3661138944       6% /fofo
```

I want to extract only one line from different other lines If I find the same path just one time. So I want to extract only one line from each multiple lines. Output expected:

```
[root@test ~]# df -P -k -t xfs | egrep '*/PATH whichI don't have/*'  
10.20.30.40:/var/contain/name1  3877121024 215982080 3661138944       6% /fofo
10.20.30.50:/var/beta/name2  3877121024 215982080 3661138944       6% /fofo
10.20.30.60:/var/alpha/name2  3877121024 215982080 3661138944       6% /fofo
```

If I find the same path I want to extract only one line from each multiple lines.
The IP address are not the same, If multiple lines contain the same address I wan to keep only one line. hope it helps

Thank you.

Comment: What happened to the lines `/var/contain/name2`, `/var/beta/toto` and `/var/alpha/name2` lines in the expected output?  How were they omitted?  Would the numbers all be the same as shown — in the IP address before the pathname and in the counts etc after the name?  They can't all be mounted simultaneously on `/fofo`?   Your MCVE ([MCVE]) does need to be minimal (5 lines is good), but it also needs to be realistic enough that we tell what's important.

Comment: I changed the IP addresses, for me when I have the same IP addressee,I want to keep only the first line with that address (as per my question)

Comment: it can be more than 5 lines, the number of lines its variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `grep` is the wrong tool for this job and Awk is a better choice (Perl or Python could also be used, and no doubt other scripting languages too).

You seem to want the first record for each IP address, which is the field up to the first colon in the log format.  That suggests you need:

```
awk -F: '!($1 in a) { print; a[$1] = 1 }'
```

Given the input show in the question, the output is:

```
10.20.30.40:/var/contain/name1  3877121024 215982080 3661138944       6% /fofo
10.20.30.50:/var/beta/name2  3877121024 215982080 3661138944       6% /fofo
10.20.30.60:/var/alpha/name2  3877121024 215982080 3661138944       6% /fofo
```

---

> Can you explain what the command does, please?

Awk uses associative arrays which can take strings as subscripts.  The `-F:` option means that Awk splits the lines into fields at colons, so `$1` is the text before the first colon (the IP address), and (in this example) `$2` is all the text after the first colon — while `$0` is the whole input line.  Awk programs are a sequence of 'pattern – action' pairs (or 'expression' or 'condition' plus 'action' pairs).  The action, if specified explicitly, is enclosed in braces (if not specified, it defaults to `print $0` — print the input line).  If a pattern is not specified, it is equivalent to matching all lines.

In this program, the condition is `!($1 in a)`, which checks whether `$1` appears as a subscript in the array `a`; the overall expression evaluates to true if the subscript does not appear.  When the condition is true, the action is taken.  That prints (implicitly `$0`), and sets `a[$1]` to `1` so that if the same IP address appears again, the condition will evaluate to false, thus preventing repeats of the IP address.

If you wanted the last entry instead of the first, you'd use a variant scheme, where each line would be saved in the correct entry in the array: `{ a[$1] = $0 }` and then you'd have an `END` pattern to run when the input is complete: `END { for (i in a) print a[i] }`.  There are endless variations on the theme.

---

> How about if I want to do the same thing but basing on the word after the IP address instead the address IP (*/word/*).

A lot depends on how you define 'word' (or *'/word/'*).  To make my life easy, I'm planning to treat a word as a contiguous set of non-blank characters.  The field separator can be a regular expression, so I'm going to use `[: ]` to split on colons or blanks; the word after the IP address is then `$2`.  The script barely changes:

```
awk -F '[: ]' '!($2 in a) { print; a[$2] = 1 }'
```

Since the names after the colon are all different in the sample data, all 5 lines appear in the output.  However, if you run the script on the same file several times (add `data data` after the script shown, where the file `data` contains your example input) and you get just one copy of the lines in the output, which is reassuring.

Comment: It works, can you explain to me your command line please. And how about if I want to do the same thing but basing on the word after the IP address instead the address IP (*/word/*) if its possible. I can't use Perl or Python because I have a big bash script and it should be only in bash. Thank you :)

Comment: @Hamadagm: I've added an explanation of what the Awk script does.

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler: Thank you for you solution and your generous explanation :)

Comment: I'm not sure why running Perl or Python from a Bash script is deemed significantly different from running Grep or Awk from a Bash script, but so be it.  I've also addressed the second half of your comment (question extension).  Note that you haven't precisely defined what you mean by 'word', and the notation _/word/_ doesn't help me understand.  I've made a reasonable guess as to what you mean — the whole pathname `/var/xyz/pqr` that appears after the IP address in the data — but even if that's wrong, you should still be able to take the ideas and apply them to your real requirement.

Comment: Yes just I tried $2 before your answer, and it works if I want to take the argument after my IP address. I learned a new thing with you its the 'awk program' and it resolve my problem thank you :)  @Jonathab Leffler

Answer (score -1):

Ok, assuming that you are interested in the /x/y part only, i think u can do it like this:

```
df -P -k -t xfs > tmpFile
cat tmpFile |cut -d: -f2|cut -d/ -f1-3|sort -u > tmpFile2
while read line; do grep $line tmpFile|head -1; done < tmpFile2
```

For the data you provided above, the output would be

```
10.20.30.40:/var/alpha/name2  3877121024 215982080 3661138944       6% /fofo
10.20.30.40:/var/beta/name2  3877121024 215982080 3661138944       6% /fofo
10.20.30.40:/var/contain/name1  3877121024 215982080 3661138944       6% /fofo
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: no I dont want to extract just the first line, I want to extract more then one line.

Comment: Not sure i understood your request then, sorry. Can you specify the input and pretended output?

Comment: Sorry my question and my command wasn't good, I modified my question and hope its easy to understand now.

Comment: I modified my answer as well... hope that's it, let me know. If you need something more ellaborate probably you can't do it with a simple command line.

Comment: when I run your answer line by line it doesn't work, I will create a bash script.

Comment: Got this output : 
grep: ola: No such file or directory
grep: 21129216: No such file or directory
grep: 3941376: No such file or directory
grep: 17187840: No such file or directory
grep: 19%: No such file or directory
grep: ola: No such file or directory
grep: 21129216: No such file or directory
grep: 3941376: No such file or directory
grep: 17187840: No such file or directory

Comment: Sorry.. cause i had your input in a file called ola :) i modified it again.

Comment: we are close to the solution :) Now  I have my single lines but there is some garabage between my lines. I will show bellow.

Comment: 10.20.30.40:/var/alpha/name2  3877121024 215982080 3661138944       6% /fofo
grep: 3877121024: No such file or directory
grep: 215982080: No such file or directory
grep: 3661138944: No such file or directory
10.20.30.40:/var/beta/name2  3877121024 215982080 3661138944       6% /fofo

Comment: Weird.. Can you please paste here what your tmpFile and tmpFile2 have after run?

Comment: @Hamadagm: we cannot see the structure of your comments — please update the question so it is vaguely comprehensible.  Include appropriate material from these comments into the question.